# Not able to unsubscribe observables in ionic 3 app

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 for my app,i am using cordova-plugin-network-information for internet connection detection event in android device, i am able to subscribe it, but not able to unsubscribe it.

I have tried rxjs, Subscription to unsubscribe from the observables, but didnt get expected result.

following is my code :

```
import {Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

private _netConnection : Subscription = new Subscription();

_netConnection = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=>{
          alert("connected");
})

_netConnection.unsubscribe();
```

But the `enter code here`above _netConnection.unsubscribe() is not working, as i am still getting the alert when connection is available.

Answer (score 1):

Use take until

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

private finalize = new Subject<void>();

this.network.onConnect().pipe(takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe(()=>{
  alert("connected");
  finalise.next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented takeWhile, but dint work as aspected. I am working on ionic 3 framework for android app. Is this issue with the native device. I think the calue after subcription is remaining into the dom, and when i am trying to unsubscribe it, it is not working. It is activated into the DOM. IS there any way to remove the value from DOM through my code.

Comment: What is in the DOM? Your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should write the `_netConnection.unsubscribe()` in `setTimeout`;

like this `setTimeout(()=> _netConnection.unsubscribe())`;

Comment: According to my need in my application i have implemented setInterval(()=> _netConnection.unsubscribe());  But this also didn't work.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the _netConnection object from DOM through some code in application. AS unsubscribe is not working in any way.

Comment: Basically my need is to run _netConnection.subscribe() on certain condition, and when that condition is false i have to unsubscribe it.

Comment: What is in the DOM, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Document Object Model (DOM)  a tree like structure in browser which holds html elements and attributes. Due to which elements and attributes are easily handled by javascript.